# Is it possible to split tweets automatically

Tags: case, twitter

When responding to a case on Twitter it's often required to split up the tweet into multiple tweets due to the answer being long. Is it possible to do this seamlessly for the end-user? The end result being that a customer support agent can type a full sentence with @username and Salesforce automatically splitting the tweet up, appending 1/3, 2/3 and 3/3 and adding the @username to the start of each individual tweet.

Comment: Have you done any research here? I ask because usually questions that do not demonstrate research on the asker's end are poorly received.

Comment: I've made sure to have a good look throughout previously asked questions, the Salesforce support site and of course search engine queries but have failed to find any similar questions. If there is anything I can elaborate my question with then please let me know.